# Regularity of harmonic functions

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I have a question on a fundamental property of harmonic functions.

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a domain. We define $H^{1}(\Omega)$ by
\begin{align*}
H^{1}(\Omega)=\{u \in L^{2}(\Omega,m) \mid |\nabla u| \in L^{2}(\Omega,m)\},
\end{align*}
where $\nabla u$ is the distributional derivative of $u$ and $m$ the Lebesgue measure on $\Omega$.

Let $b:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^d$ is a bounded measurable function on $\Omega$.

Let $f$ be a function on $\Omega$ satisfying the following property: for any compact subset $K$ of $\Omega$ there exists $u \in H^{1}(\Omega)$ such that $f=u$, $m$-a.e. on $K$. We further assume that $f$ satisfies 
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega}(\nabla f, \nabla g)\,dm+\int_{\Omega}(b,\nabla f)g\,dm=0
\end{align*}
for any $g \in C^{\infty}_{0}(\Omega)$. Namely, $f$ is a distributional harmonic function on $\Omega$.

Can we show that $f \in C^{2}(\Omega)$?

If $b=0$, it follows that $f \in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ by the Weyl's lemma.

Comment: Now, I found a related result. In this book https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540411604, the authors claim that $f \in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ provided that $b$ is smooth. See Corollary 8.11, p186.

Comment: Is b a vector-valued function?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Yes. You're right!

Comment: So the equation you are studying is $-\Delta f +b\cdot\nabla f =0.$ If $b$ is constant, the smoothness of $f$ is a consequence of the standard elliptic regularity (Folland Real Analysis, theorem 9.26). If not, then you should consult some other book on elliptic equations, like you did.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you for your comment. By the way, $f$ is smooth when $b$ is bounded?

Comment: I don't know,  but it might be. The book of Gilbarg and Trudinger surely covers this.